# How do I align the start of each \item in an enumerate environment with left-aligned labels?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate, indentation, enumitem

Here's my MWE using LuaLaTeX and the `scrbook` KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass[%
% draft,
twoside,
headings=openany, % parts/chapters start on any page whether it's odd or even
DIV=15, % division factor
BCOR=12.5mm, % binding correction
headsepline=1.5pt, % header line
footsepline=0.4pt, % footer line
numbers=noenddot, % no dots at the end of section numbering
% chapterprefix
]{scrbook} % 11pt, a4paper (default)
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{setspace}\setdisplayskipstretch{}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[enumerate]{font={\bfseries}}
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), align=left}
    % shift footer down
    \ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.odd}
    \ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.even}
    \ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{scrheadings.foot.oneside}
    \ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.odd}
    \ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.even}
    \ModifyLayer[addvoffset=.6ex]{plain.scrheadings.foot.oneside}
\begin{document}
    \onehalfspacing
    \KOMAoptions{DIV=current}
    \addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily} % page number font
    \ifoot*{} % inner footer
    \cfoot*{} % central footer
    \ofoot*{\pagemark} % outer footer
\begin{enumerate}
% No. 05
\item[5.] Prove the following:
    \begin{enumerate}
            % (i)
            \item If \(a < b\) and \(c < d\), then \(a + c < b + d\).
            % (ii)
            \item If \(a < b\), then \(-b < -a\). 
            % (iii)
            \item If \(a < b\) and \(c > d\), then \(a - c < b - d\). 
            % (iv)
            \item If \(a < b\) and \(c > 0\), then \(ac < bc\).
            % (v)
            \item If \(a < b\) and \(c < 0\), then \(ac > bc\).
            % (vi)
            \item If \(a > 1\), then \(a^2 > a\).
            % (vii)
            \item If \(0 < a < 1\), then \(a^2 < a\).
            % (viii)
            \item If \(0 \leq a < b\) and \(0 \leq c < d\), then \(ac < bd\).
            % (ix)
            \item If \(0 \leq a < b\), then \(a^2 < b^2\). (Use \textbf{(viii)}.)
            % (x)
            \item If \(a, b \geq 0\) and \(a^2 < b^2\), then \(a < b\).  (Use \textbf{(ix)}, backwards.)
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here's the compiled result.

[image]

My question is: ***How do I align the start of each `\item` (which are the "If"s in this specific case)?***

I've tried reading the [`enumitem`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) package documentation for more information on how to use and adjust the parameters: `leftmargin`, `labelindent`, `labelwidth`, `labelsep`, `labelsep*`, `itemindent`, etc.

[image]

[image]

and I've read several different but related TeX SE questions but I am still rather confused after tinkering with them using `\setlist` and they would often act weirdly when using nested `enumerate`s (the first and second layer labels would be touching each other or the horizontal space between the second layer label and the items would be to big).

My goal would be to typeset something like this:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

For the second level of `enumerate` you need to increase `labelwidth` so that be wider of items labels, and `leftmargin` for the same amount + `labelsep` of the first level of enumerate`. For example:

```
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.},  % <--- ccorrected
                          labelsep=1em}  % <--- added
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), align=left,
                          labelwidth=2.2em, leftmargin=3.2em} % <--- added
```

Wit this change the list will be as follows:

[image]

A complete (real) MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} % 11pt, a4paper (default)
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,
                          mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math} % Math fonts
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\usepackage{setspace}
    \setdisplayskipstretch{}

\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.},  % <--- ccorrected
                          labelsep=1em}  % <--- added
    \setlist[enumerate,2]{label=(\roman*), align=left,
                          labelwidth=2.2em, leftmargin=3.2em} % <--- added
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Prove the following:
    \begin{enumerate}[start=5] % in real document remove this option
\item If \(a < b\) and \(c < d\), then \(a + c < b + d\).
\item If \(a < b\), then \(-b < -a\).
\item If \(a < b\) and \(c > d\), then \(a - c < b - d\).
\item If \(a < b\) and \(c > 0\), then \(ac < bc\).
\item If \(a < b\) and \(c < 0\), then \(ac > bc\).
\item If \(a > 1\), then \(a^2 > a\).
\item If \(0 < a < 1\), then \(a^2 < a\).
\item If \(0 \leq a < b\) and \(0 \leq c < d\), then \(ac < bd\).
\item If \(0 \leq a < b\), then \(a^2 < b^2\). (Use \textbf{(viii)}.)
\item If \(a, b \geq 0\) and \(a^2 < b^2\), then \(a < b\).  (Use \textbf{(ix)}, backwards.)
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok so I've tried this and it seem to work but how do I solve [the distance between nested labels?](https://imgur.com/lvOMswR)

Comment: I want add a distance between the first-layer label and the second-layer label without affecting the distance between the second-layer label and the second-layer items

Comment: @FarrelAhmed, oh I overlook this. I will add this ASAP.

Comment: @FarrelAhmed, done!

Comment: Ah, I see, I think I'm beginning to understand the parameters more now. I've tried your solutions and used `labelsep=0.5em`, `leftmargin=3em`, `labelwidth=2.5em` instead for my personal taste and it worked! Thank you :D